# Number of integers for which $\Omega=k$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, analytic-number-theory, arithmetic-functions

for every $x>0$, I'm trying to find out the number of positive integers $n\leq x$ such that $\Omega(n)=k$ for all $k\geq 1$ in $N$, where $\Omega(n)=\Omega(p_1^{\mu_1}\cdot\ldots\cdot p_j^{\mu_j})=\mu_1+\ldots+\mu_j$.

Or, at least, I need informations about the order of growth of the function $f(k,x)=$ number of positive integers $n\leq x$ such that $\Omega(n)=k$.

Maybe someone can give me a hint to know in what direction I must go.

Answer (score 1):

One of the easy consequences of the prime number theorem is that $$\lim_{x\to+\infty} \frac{\#\{1\leq n \leq x: \Omega(n)=k\}(\log x )}{x (\log \log x )^{k-1} } =\frac{1}{(k-1)!}.$$ You can read about it in  Montgomery & Vaughan 'Multiplicative Number Theory' volume 1, chapter 7, exercise 3.

Comment: Well are you suggesting to follow the step MV's used in ex7.3 to get the estimate for $\omega(n)$ instead of $\Omega(n)?$

Comment: The two omegas always behave in the same way. So any asymptotic for omega should be valid usually for Omega as well.